# How do I open the Google Drive folder of the file I am editing?

Tags: google-drive

It used to be that if I clicked the white icon with the colored background in the top-left, it would take me to my folder on Google Drive.

[image: Google Docs header]

Now it takes me to these worthless links:

> https://docs.google.com/document/u/0/
>
> https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/u/0/
>
> https://docs.google.com/presentation/u/0/

If it navigated me back to the folder, I would know exactly where to go to find the next file I need, instead of having to search for it by whichever one of these dumb search options Google gives us. How about sort by "Folder" instead of "Last modified", "Last edited by me", "Last opened by me", and "Title"?

Oh, they give me a link to the Drive though, a useless link to the root:

[image: Google Docs menu]

But that's rhetorical. Onto my actual question. Can I disable these pages and have that link take me back to the Google Drive folder like it used to? Is there a new way to navigate back to the Google Drive folder?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is the way it works 13th Dec 2017:

1. Click the little folder symbol next to the file name.
2. Folder name appears. Next to it, click the symbol of opening in new window/tab.

[image: How to open the Google Drive folder of the file you're just editing.]

I wish it was just the blue left upper symbol. :D

Comment: I noticed this a few weeks ago. I mean, the icon is intuitive but it would be nice if the folder name also opened a tab with the folder.

Comment: Possibly the only good news to come out of 2020: this still works in August 2020.

Comment: This only works, I believe, if you _own_ the file. If you are given a link to a file created by someone else you can see the _name_ of the folder it is in via "File -> Document Details", but not get the link to that folder. (As of November 2020.)

Answer (score 16):

Good news! Google has listened and re-added the ability to open the folder that your document is in, just click the little folder icon:

[image: "This item is in" folder link]

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't work anymore

Comment: Try refreshing the page or checking the sharing settings on the file. If it's in a shared folder it might not show up.

Comment: Now you click on the folder icon, and the name of the folder the document is in will be at the top, and to the left will be a "open in new window" icon.

Comment: This only works if the file is in My Drive. It doesn't work if it's in a Team Drive.

Comment: @Merchako works for me if it's in a team drive. See my answer; the folder it is stored in is a shared team drive.

Answer (score 2):

In 2024, this is now the way:

1. To the right of your document name is an icon of a folder with an arrow on it, used for moving your document to a new folder. Click this.
   [image: Folder with rightward arrow highlighted with circle around it; below is a tooltip saying "Move"]
2. This will open a ~dialog window for moving your document to a new folder. The current folder name is listed. To the right of the current folder name is an icon of a square with an arrow pointing to the upper right. Click this to open that folder in a new tab.
   [image: screenshot showing the described icon]

Comment: Isn't this the same as what @zedofin posted but with a UI update?

Comment: @NobleUplift Hmm, I suppose you are right! I did look through the answers while trying to solve this, and for some reason the old "folder" icon being redesigned and tooltipped to "move" felt so very different my brain did not see Zedofin's answer as a solution. I'll certainly throw an upvote over there.